# Passing props in React Typescript using custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have made a custom `useToggler` hook, and i am trying to pass toggle props from it to button child in Header. When i try toggle={toggle} i get error:

> Type '{toggle: () => void;}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

How can i achieve that with typescript?

```
import './style/app.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer'
import Backdrop from'./components/Backdrop'
import useToggler from "./components/UseToggler";

const App = () => {
    const [show, toggle]=useToggler()

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header toggle={toggle} />
            <SideDrawer/>
            <Backdrop/>
            <main style={{marginTop:'56px'}}>
                <p>Page content</p>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get a similar error, since you're violating the interface typecheck. The Component should have a mandatory prop. You can avoid this error by spreading the props you want to pass as:

```
<Header {...toggler} />
```

Comment: thank you! and how would i pass this props to child <DrawerToggleButton/> inside <Header/>

Comment: `<Header><DrawerToggleButton/></Header>`

Comment: i have done that already, but i need to send props one more level down...
but i cannot do <DrawerToggleButton {...toggle}/>

Comment: That's because typescript doesn't know in advance that `{...toggler}` includes `toggle`. you can do: `<DrawerToggleButton {...props}/>`

Comment: great thank you, i hope i dont bother you... now inside <DrawerToggleButton/> i have Button and  i need to put onClick property with toggle function...<button onClick={?}